# Regex to match the rest of string after the 4th character

Tags: regex

Here's the list of my random numbers

```
r7l5ndecvz9
0qb6rtxsd6ui
dj5iuzpq5vn
rysquf0jkek
435vw5h2qag
```

And what I want to do is to match or trim the rest after the number of characters (lets say 4), and I want to output as this:

```
r7l5
0qb6
dj5i
rysq
435v
```

See, I only want to match the rest of the characters after the 4th character. I tried this regex expression `.{4}\b` but it only matches the last 4 characters. I also tried this expression `^(\S\S\S\S)` but it only matches the first 4 characters. I want to match the rest AFTER the 4th character. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `....(.*)` ? Ignore 4 whatevers and match the remaining, using a group?

Comment: But in this case ... why not simply [4:]  via slicing?

Comment: Perhaps it is easier to use string functions to take the first 4 characters.

Comment: no I'm trying to match or trim after the 4th character. I don't want to match the first 4 characters. I'm trying to match everything after the 4th character.

Comment: [4:] removes the first 4 things and keeps the rest. `r'....(.*)'` does the same . you need to use the 1st matched GROUP - https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax not the full match ... [how-do-capture-groups-work-wrt-python-regular-expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861060/how-do-capture-groups-work-wrt-python-regular-expressions)

Comment: Ok it almost worked, it only captured starting the 4th character, what if I want the 5th character? I tried `[5:].....(.*)` to no avail.

Comment: A flavor-neutral regex:
^.{4}(.*)$

Comment: @TonyR that didn't work, it only selects the entire string.

Comment: Capture group 1 ($1) contains the second part of the string.
If you want the first part, then 
^(.{4})

Answer (score 0):

Given the sample inputs and outputs, you want to capture the first four characters. The regex for this is `^(.{4})`

The caret matches the start of the line, the dot matches any character, the 4 in braces indicates 4 occurrences, and the parentheses capture the result for later access.

Here's working Python code:

```
import re
inputs = ['r7l5ndecvz9','0qb6rtxsd6ui','dj5iuzpq5vn','rysquf0jkek','435vw5h2qag']
for str in inputs:
    match = re.search('^(.{4})',str)
    print(match.group(0))
```